# Git make the master branch have contents of a previous commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using bitbucket using git. My recent changes have affected the working of my project. As a result, I would like to overwrite all my recent changes.

I need my master branch to contain only those changes till a previous commit with commit id say 'b43fbf'.

What is the git command to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revert to a previous Git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit)

Answer (score 2):

Run `git reset --hard b43fbf`

This resets your current branch and your working tree to the commit `b43fbf` (all changes are then lost).

For other options see [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit)

Comment: It worked. but now it is in a detached HEAD state. I am not able to push because of that.

Comment: Then you were on detached HEAD state before. Make sure you are on the master branch e.g. by "git checkout master --force" and then issue the reset command.

Comment: But beware that, as the names suggest, `reset --hard` and anything including `--force` are dangerous commands. Understand what you're doing before running them.